# Flask SQLAlchemy query.all() returns all ids only

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following code below

```
@app.route('/all', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_feedback():
  all_feedback = db.session.query(Feedback).all()
  result = feedbacks_schema.dump(all_feedback)
  return jsonify(result)
```

I am using postman to make a request to get all feedback from my feedback table I have (fyi: I am using postgreSQL). I am getting all my feedback but only the `ids` from my table. What I want is all the columns for each row.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
all_feedback = Feedback.query.all()
```

Comment: I actually tried that before but the result is the same. The result looks like `[{"id": 1}, {"id"; 2}, ... ]`

Comment: Actually, after trying and trying I realized that my schema fields were wrong. I'm not sure what I was thinking but after fixing it I do get back the right data